# unable to drag and drop files from macOS Mojave to Macbook running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: screen-sharing

I'm currently connected from my iMac (macOS Mojave) to my Macbook running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my local network via the Screen Share application; however, I'm unable to drag and drop files from my local iMac desktop to my Ubuntu Macbook as I've ordinarily transferred between macOS devices on my local network via Screen Share. I've enabled "**Screen Sharing**" and "**File Sharing**" within my iMac **System Preferences > Sharing** options and enabled "**File Sharing**" within **Settings > Sharing** on my Ubuntu Macbook and disabled the "require-encryption" option within the path `/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/` via the dconf editor- why am I unable to share files or copy/paste between the systems?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear you want to drag N drop a file from a Mac running macOS to a Mac Running Ubuntu?

Comment: Correct- I'll add a screenshot for clarification; ordinarily I can drag and drop files or copy/paste between my iMac and Macbook Pro (both running Mojave) via the Screen Share application but I'm unable to do so from my iMac to the hackintosh as described within the question.

Comment: A Hackintosh is a type of non-Apple computer designed to run unauthorized versions of macOS; however, you say you have a iMac and a MacBook... so why are you using "hackintosh' in the title of your question? Ubuntu running on a MacBook is not considered a Hackintosh. You also say you're running Ubuntu 18.04, yet the Software Updater says your running 16.04, so is18.04 a typo?

Comment: You're right- it was my misunderstanding that a retrofitted macbook running another type of OS (ie Ubuntu 18.04) instead of any macOS was a hackintosh; my mistake, but the issue still persists as described- thanks!  Also that was an older screen-shot prior to upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I am thinking that whatever you are using on the Linux side doesn't support whatever Apple did to VNC to enable file transfer through the viewer window. Just a guess tho as I am not a Linux guy...